# How do I preselect an item in NSPopUpButton bound to core data?

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, swift3, nspopupbutton

I have an NSPopUpButton with bindings to core data. I need to preselect an item in the list dynamically when the view is loaded. Is there a way to get a notification when the NSArrayController is ready? Or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the selected object of the popup button to a property of the VC. Make sure the property is set before the popup button is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your selection using GCD with

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
  // Set selection.
}
```

You could call this from the array or view / window controller's awakeFromNib for example.

Comment: Why the 0.1 seconds?